# Linux Debian - Sync 2 machines

Tags: linux, debian, linux-mint, sync

I migrated recently from Windows to Linux Mint (LMDE to be precise, but I don't think the exact distro will matter). I am hooked to it, and have my own configuration and shortcuts, and highly customized:

- I have a few flatpak apps that I use often, and are configured in a certain way
- Keyboard shortcuts are customised
- I use conky
- My Bashrc is customized
- A few more tweaks

Now... Is it possible for me to seamlessly sync two machines, running the same OS? I wish to use two desktops (not laptops) - Where as soon as I power one on, it will download the latest version of my config/tweaks, and help me work as if I were on the other?

To take things one step forward, I even plan to install the OS on a portable USB drive. Hence, I could literally carry a PC in my pocket & borrow anyone's desktop, and use it as if it were my own.

Do pls note: all my data is already synced using Google Drive. I have no concerns there. It's just the apps and the config files, for each app that I need to sync.

PS: syncthing.net will not be ideal in this case. That requires that at least one of the machines (peer-network) is powered on at all times.

Suggestions pls?

Some valid questions asked:

- My data directory is already synced with Google drive. That is about 7 GB or so, and that is not a concern here. I am happy to continue with the Google Sync.
- For everything else, the data size should be close to 500 MB. This will include the config files.
- Next we have browsers and their profiles/data. That should be another 3 GB or so.
- The sync can be manually triggered. This can be when I switch my workstations or boot off from a USB

Comment: If you have a way to setup a network drive,  take a look at [freefilesync](https://freefilesync.org/)

Comment: Installing the OS on a USB drive is possible, but seems completely irrelevant to this question. However, a lot of **relevant** information is missing: how much of the data you need synced and how often: is it just a bunch of configs or do you need to get back to your work projects which are potentially terabytes of data? Is it possible to sync directly or are you looking for more of a "backup and restore" solution? Two barebone options that come to mind are rsync (running on boot/after waking) and mounting the drive over e.g. sshfs. I'd probably rsync if it's mostly just ricing/customization.

Comment: Thanks @Lodinn. Updated my question now.

Comment: You need to be carefull what you sync as two systems are never 100% the same.  Settings for a tool could depend on that tool version and get updated when you update the tool.
One method that I use is to have a "home_share" on a synced cloud folder and link from my home directory to items on that cloud folder.
For instance, `ln -s .bashrc ../home_share/bashrc` (without a dot as a cloud does not like hidden files/directorys).  Linking/updating the links can be scripted.  I link .ssh to ../ssh_dir, .gitconfig to gitconfig, etc.

Comment: Check out these relevant Q&A's in the Unix&Linux stackexchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=sync+two+machines

Answer (score 0):

It might work if you were to create a new private Git repository (I don't know if there is a max size), with all your config files (browsers usually store data in a specific directory) and user data, then create a bash script that downloads all this data, overwriting the stuff on the disk, on startup. Or checks it's own version against the Git repo and sees if it has changed, then just leave that in the background. You could also mess around with Rsync and see if you can sync some of the larger files that way. I've done file version syncing (code, mainly) to a Git repo, and it works great. It would not involve Google Drive though...

Comment: Thanks e7eth. Fair idea, but will this be a logistical nightmare? We are talking about syncing multiple directories (on the linux OS) with git; plus a few files (bashrc, conkyrc, etc). Maybe there are tools/scripts that can do this automatically: check for the latest version and sync accordingly

Comment: Yeah, it's probably not the simplest way out there, but it does work if nothing else can be found